# Docker pull does not work on Windows container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have the issue when trying to pull any image when switched to windows containers (Docker Desktop 4.19.0 (106363))

I do not use VPN, I use dns 8.8.8.8 on my windows desktop.

On docker pull command I recive the error :

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```